# DIV Becomes rectangular when scaled

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV called `square` that's fine as a square when viewed at more than `500px` in width.

```css
.squareholder {
display: flex;
width: 80%;
justify-content: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.square {
width: 12vw;
height: 12vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
margin-right: 1vw;
background-color: #ff0000;
border-radius: 2vh;
align-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.square {
width: 30vh;
height: 30vh;
margin-left: 1vw;
margin-right: 1vw;
background-color: #ff0000;
border-radius: 2vh;
align-content: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class ="squareholder">
<div class ="square"><h1>Text</h1></div>
</div>
```

When viewed normally, the DIV is a square. When the window is resized it stretched out.

Any ideas why given that the height and width properties remain the same?

I know it's to do with flex but if I add three in a row;

```css
.squareholder {
display: flex;
width: 80%;
justify-content: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.square {
width: 12vw;
height: 12vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
margin-right: 1vw;
background-color: #ff0000;
border-radius: 2vh;
align-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.square {
width: 30vh;
height: 30vh;
margin-left: 1vw;
margin-right: 1vw;
background-color: #ff0000;
border-radius: 2vh;
align-content: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class ="squareholder">
<div class ="square"><h1>Text</h1></div>
<div class ="square"><h1>Text1</h1></div>
<div class ="square"><h1>Text2</h1></div>
</div>
```

All of the boxes are in a row. I need them still in a row, just to remain squares when smaller. I think it's to do with `display: flex;` being used but I'm not sure what other solution would keep it as `[] [] []`

Rather than;

`[]
 []
 []`

When resizing the browser width.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because for small screens, the width continues to shrink while the height is the same. Using `vh` in your media query is trying to accommodate for this and it creates a rectangle.

I would make your css uniform if you want to prevent the red squares from becoming rectangles on smaller screens.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vxgsq15u/

Comment: I've tried this but I do need the squares to be slightly larger to accommodate for the smaller screen? Thanks

Comment: Sure. You can do this by expanding the width of `.squareholder` to something higher (right now it's at 80%). Check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/vxgsq15u/2/

Comment: Thank you, It still doesn't make sense, I understand why, it's just strange.

Comment: This video helped me a lot, I watch it on 1.25x speed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWFqGsXxJ1E